# Multiple Python venv in a single quarto website?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-venv, quarto

I wanted to create a website with a list of all my quarto presentations. So I created a quarto website and moved all my presentations into subfolders. I include the presentations as iframes into a table in my main website index.qmd.

```
presentations
│   ├── _quarto.yml
│   ├── _site
│   ├── index.qmd
│   ├── styles.css
│   ├── presentation_1
│   │   ├── Pipfile
│   │   ├── Pipfile.lock
│   │   ├── presentation_1.qmd
│   ├── presentation_2
│   │   ├── Pipfile
│   │   ├── Pipfile.lock
│   │   ├── presentation_2.qmd
...
```

However when rendering the whole website I realized that my presentations use separate virtual Python environments (I use `pipenv`, see the Pipfiles above). So to render my website successfully I have to navigate to each presentation subdirectory, activate the venv for that directory and then render with quarto only the content of the subdirectory. In the end I activate the global environment and render the whole website.

Is there are more convenient way to do that? Is it maybe possible to specify a venv for each qmd file separately? Because I do not want to move all dependencies into my global environment. The dependencies might be conflicting.

Comment: In most cases it is not necessary to activate a virtual environment. Instead one can simply call the Python binary of this virtual environment explicilty, for example: `path/to/venv/bin/python ...`. -- Maybe that helps.